# How to make interesting movies for online teaching?

Tags: animation

I am fascinated by [this movie about string theory](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z694S3cGCg0). 
What kind of software did they use to create the animations? What would you suggest to create similar movies ?

Comment: I suggest piracy, uhhh borrowing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash is a very powerful program, but [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) is a free, open source, application to create 2D animations compatible with Flash.

Answer (score 2):

Two programs that you might want to take a look at for your use or inspiration are:

- [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) - 3D modeling, rendering and animation
- [Pencil](http://www.pencil-animation.org/) - 2D traditional bitmap and vector drawing and animation

Both are free and open source.

[Here](http://osflash.org/open_source_flash_projects) is some information on open source Flash development.

Comment: Pencil looks very interesting.

Comment: Interesting, but quite unstable :(

Answer (score 1):

That particular video was created using [Adobe Flash](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash/). It's fairly easy to make the same kinds of movies with Flash, but the IDE is commercial, so if you were looking for free software you're out of luck (although I'm sure there are free alternatives to it somewhere). I wouldn't really be able to recommend any other alternatives to Flash for making animations, because it doesn't get much better.

Comment: Do you think flash is overkill for the casual user ? (not much for the price, rather for the time needed to use it proficiently). I'm not planning to throw $699 into it, I think it's too much. just curious.

Comment: In all honesty, yes I do. But I don't know of a free alternative.